# How to enable session resumption on Netty Client side

Tags: ssl, netty

Reading [an article](https://www.maxcdn.com/blog/ssl-performance-myth/) about the cost of SSL handshake, I saw the possibility to have **session tickets and session resumption** to avoid paying the cost of re-establishing the session.

In my architecture, I use Netty in the client side and Tomcat on the server side. Googling I saw several guides to enable it on nginx and other server implementation, but for the netty implementation on the client side, I couldn't find anything.

At this point, I was wondering if it was directly managed by SSLEngine for me at the client side, and I have to do nothing, or there is some "secretive" config I have to turn on to benefit from the SSL resumption on the client side.

Is there any reason why I would like to disable it? (I saw several questions on SO)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Java's SSL implementaion don't support session tickets, I lodged a feature request for this a few years go.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8134497

Luckily Netty lets you switch to OpenSSL implementations that do support session tickets and better yet can be directly swapped into your code.

See http://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html for details but you basically just add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

to your POM file and specify OpenSSL as your provider when setting up the context.

```
  SslContext sslContext =
  SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                 .sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL)
                 .build();
```

Apache Portable Runtime and OpenSSL need to be installed on the system.

Comment: actually if you use the -static artifact it is static linked and so there is no need for apr and openssl to be installed. It will just work ;)

Comment: Does that ticket refer just to OpenJDK and not the Oracle one?